# For Loop inside Parallel.for

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, parallel.for

After lot of googling from yesterday I am posting this question

I am working on multithreading and I am using Parrallel.For, I want to know how do we use for loop inside Parrallel.for. As far as I read this is not the best practice but for now I have to do for my RND work

```
     int dataPerBatch = 100;
ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, totalLoops, (i) => UpdateRecords(i, lstVins));

 public void UpdateRecords(int i, List<string> lst)
    {

      start = (i * dataPerBatch) + 1;
      end = dataPerBatch * (i + 1);
     //Inner For Loop 
     for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
        {
            // Call individual list object to web-api and fetch the result in new list object

            // Here the start and end value keep on chahnging
        }

       //  Call this collection again to the web- api and do bulk update
  }
```

But the problem is the inner for loop does not wait, it over laps with the muti thread value (when parrallel.for iterates)I have tried using lock but of no use.

Please Note: **I have not pasted the entire code but just the skeleton**

Comment: Are `start` and `end` defined inside `UpdateRecords` or shared across all parallel loops?

Comment: Why bother?  Parallel.For() already makes batches, you're trying to be too clever.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variables `start` and `end` outside the method, so all threads will share the same variables. Make them local to the method so that the threads have their own set of variables:

```
int start = (i * dataPerBatch) + 1;
int end = dataPerBatch * (i + 1);
```